# How to retain the formula even when I clear contents of the table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel table that some contain formula and some not, but when I clear contents of the table, it also cleared my formula in the selected cells range.

How to retain the formula even when I clear contents of the table?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about having a cell blank if the source values for its formula are missing.  Wrap the formula in an IF test that tests whether the source cell is blank.  If so, set the result to "null" instead of the current formula result (two double quotes with nothing between them: ""  Clear just the source cells.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're saying. This is my formula '=IF(ISBLANK($A6),"",IF(OR(ISBLANK($C6),ISBLANK($E6)),0,NETWORKDAYS($C6,$E6)))'. Where should I put the IF test?

Comment: You haven't actually described anything specific about your spreadsheet, so there's no way to interpret your formula.  But in general, say A6, C6, and E6 must all be non-blank, and your original formula was `=formula`.  You would do something like: `=IF(OR(ISBLANK($A6),ISBLANK($C6),ISBLANK($E6)),"",formula)`.

Answer (score 1):

Select your table and run this short macro:

```
Sub KlearData()
    Dim r As Range

    For Each r In Selection
        If Not r.HasFormula Then
            r.ClearContents
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel formulas are "compartmental" macros that run in a single cell. If I make a column "A" and navigate to cell **(A10)** I would enter my formula or expression in cell **(A10)** marking cell **(A1 thru A9)** for example **[SUM=(A1,A9)]**  This would add all the numbers in cell **(A1 thru A9)** and the sum result would be displayed in cell **(A10)**. You can you can change whatever data you want in the **(A1 thru A9)** cells but never delete the formula in cell **(A10)** and you should be good to go. Good luck

> ***Resource -*** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-training-9bc05390-e94c-46af-a5b3-d7c22f6990bb

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an ounce of **protection**!

**First**.

- You have to prepare your sheet for a "look" that tells the user (it
  might be just yourself) that the sheet contains sensitive areas that
  aren't to be deleted.

**How?**

- One way is to color/shade in the cells that are to be used for data
  INPUT.

[image]

**Second**.

- Unlock the cells that are intended for INPUT (ie Tables). See illustration below.

**How?**

- Home Tab → Format → Lock (toggle to unlock). See illustration below.

Now that the **cells** are **unlocked** and **ready for INPUT**, you **must protect** the rest of the **sheet**.

**Protect the sheet?**

- Home Tab → Format → Protect. See illustration below.

You can **protect the sheet** (just leave the defaults) with or without password.

### [image]

***Now your Sheet has locked and unlocked cells and your Sheet is protected. The cells will only be visibly locked/unlocked when any sheet is in "Protect Mode".***

***Now when you Clear Contents, you are only allowed to clear the cells that are unlocked (while the sheet is Protected). If the sheet is unprotected, then the cells, locked or unlocked, will all be vulnerable.***